# GDPR and Office 365

Tags: geolocation, office365

We are based in Australia and have an office in London. Due to UK GDPR, we keep UK data hosted in the UK, meaning we need to create a new Office 365 tenant for them. We are too small (<2500 users) to use Office 365 Multi-Geo.

Multi-tenancy has a few issues, such as needing guest accounts to access each others Teams, tenant specific accounts to access shared mailboxes, etc.

If you are in a similar situation, how are you handling collaboration and communications between tenants?